# Shuffling to yourself in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Is it the case that, during the shuffle, the intermediate (map) outputs from host A which are destined for host B are sent over the network iff A != B?  Does this behavior depend on Hadoop itself, or come for free based on the underlying OS's implementation of TCP/IP, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The map output file's partitions are made available to the reducers over HTTP.
If A and B are same or different should not make any difference.

Comment: shouldn't it?  Shouldn't a request to http://<my machine's ip>:<map output servlet port> end up hitting the loopback interface?